# Polymer 0.9 compute in repeat template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to use a compute in a template repeat block. Although the compute works out of the template it doesn't work in it. Is there a way for a compute to work in the template repeat?

Not Working

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuPages}}">
            <li class="c-text">
                <div>{{computeTest(testParam)}}</div>
                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Working

```
<template>
    <div>{{computeTest(testParam)}}</div>
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuPages}}">
            <li class="c-text">
                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

[Not Working](http://bstavroulakis.com/demos/stackoverflow/polymer-09-loop/compute-not-working.html)

[Working](http://bstavroulakis.com/demos/stackoverflow/polymer-09-loop/compute-working.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to latest Polymer! It worked for me...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think my answer above is relevant! Polymer is in Beta and with Polymer files from today (ver 9.1 I think), it worked (I tested locally on my machine).

Comment: I meant Polymer ver: 0.9.1

Comment: If I wrote: "it worked for me", that mean that **I have verified it**'. And I also answered "**Update** to latest Polymer" which **is the solution** of this question. Should people hunting "reputation" have higher priority than "relevant answers" on Stackoverflow? Ok, if I get on more of this kind of welcoming (when I tried to help), I probably newer going to try to help anybody on this site again...

Comment: The update from 0.9 to 0.9.1 fixed it actually. Thanks!